# NSURL _CFURLRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d96de0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to show a webpage in a uiWebView but my app crashes. the app crashes when trying to call

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

I get the following error message:

> 2013-12-07 04:06:09.443 Reac[5374:2703] -[NSURL _CFURLRequest]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d96de0 2013-12-07
>   04:06:09.444 Reac[5374:2703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL
>   _CFURLRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d96de0'

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@interface WebViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.webView.delegate=self;
self.allowNavigation=NO;

NSURLRequest *urlRequest =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Needs to be

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

You should read the documentation first or do a simple search